# I can't send data from JSX form in React App to PHP file. PHP file works but creates empty entries in the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, xampp

I'm on MacOS, using XAMPP as server with PHP, MySQL database and React App as frontend.
I'm trying to make an ecommerce site as my university project. I almost finished the front end and tried to make register form which sends data from .jsx file in Visual Studio Code to .php file in XAMPP folder using POST method. Apache is working, MySQL database is working and PHP file can connect to database, creates a table or if it already exists then just adds a new record to that table, however it's always empty with no data inside from the JSX form.

Here's my JSX form:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './RegistrationForm.scss'

const RegisterForm = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            console.log(formData);
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost/Register.php', formData);
            console.log(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                First name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="firstName"
                    value={formData.firstName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Last name:
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName"
                    value={formData.lastName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email:
                <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Password:
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    value={formData.password}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default RegisterForm;
```

and here's my PHP file in XAMPP folder:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "store";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create table if it doesn't exist
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  password VARCHAR(50)
)";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // Insert data from form into table
    $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, password)
VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

So far I tried at least 3 methods of sending that data to php file.
POST, axios.POST and POST with XMLHttpRequest however none of them works, I had CORS errors which I'm not sure how I got rid of. I added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); in every possible config inside the XAMPP folder,I tried enabling CORS in Chrome and safari with addons, I tried different filepaths/urls to .php fle. Nothing helps
If I set static data in php file to add to the database then it works and adds that data however when trying to compile that php trough jsx form it's always empty entries.
The current code above has no errors but creates empty entries.
Can someone help me or explain what's wrong with my code? Is it an issue with the CORS? Code doesn't work? Problem with the XAMPP? I've been trying to solve this for past few days but I just can't find any solution. The current form is very basic I will make it better once php file will receive any data at all.

Comment: I recommend debugging by splitting this problem in two.  First, check if the POST data is being received by your PHP script at all (add `var_dump($_POST);` and check that it's not empty).  Second, confirm that PHP can add the data to the database (code looks good apart from a big security vulnerability - you need to use bound parameters rather than inserting values directly into SQL code).  From your description it sounds like there's a problem with your client-side code not POSTing data appropriately.  Maybe check the encoding?

Comment: @RobEyre yes client was an issue and POST was empty or some other errors were occurring. Axios method just wouldn't work and gave me a lot of different errors or just wasn't sending any data to the PHP. I had to use 'new URLSearchParams();' to make it work. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working.  Please do consider that security vulnerability in your PHP code though.

Answer (score 0):

Client was an issue, server side was fine. POST works now properly with the new JSX code below. PHP code is the same.

> ```
> const Formularz = () => {
> const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
> const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
>
> const handleSubmit = (e) => {
>     e.preventDefault();
>
>     
>     const formData = new URLSearchParams();
>     formData.append('firstName', firstName);
>     formData.append('lastName', lastName);
>
>     
>     fetch('http://localhost/Register.php', {
>         method: 'POST',
>         body: formData,
>     })
>         .then(response => response.text())
>         .then(data => {
>             // Obsługa odpowiedzi z serwera
>             console.log('Odpowiedź z serwera:', data);
>         })
>         .catch(error => {
>             // Obsługa błędów
>             console.error('Błąd:', error);
>         });
> };
>
> return (
>     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
>         <label>
>             Imię:
>             <input
>                 type="text"
>                 value={firstName}
>                 onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
>             />
>         </label>
>         <br />
>         <label>
>             Nazwisko:
>             <input
>                 type="text"
>                 value={lastName}
>                 onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
>             />
>         </label>
>         <br />
>         <button type="submit">Wyślij</button>
>     </form>
> ); };   export default Formularz;
> ```